# how can I select an array from a list in ansible

Tags: ansible

I am trying to extract rooms so i can use them with a playbook
am prompting the user which room they want to work with but how do I use that variable to return "rooms":["test1","test2"] when I select A for example

```
---
- hosts: localhost
  become: no


  vars:
   - sites: [
       { "site":"A","rooms":["test1","test2"]},
       { "site":"B","rooms":["test3","test4"]},
       { "site":"C","rooms":["test5","test6"]},
       { "site":"D","rooms":["test7"] }
     ]
  vars_prompt:
        - name: site
          prompt: "whats site we working with A,B,C,D ?"
          private: no

  tasks:
     - name: "debug"
       ansible.builtin.debug:
        msg: "{{ sites | ( selectattr('site', 'equalto', site ) }}"
```

Comment: An array and a list are the exact same thing. I don’t think you can actually have a list at the root of à `vars` btw.

Answer (score 1):

Convert the list to a dictionary

```yaml
  sites_dict: "{{ sites|items2dict(key_name='site', value_name='rooms') }}"
```

gives

```yaml
  sites_dict:
    A: [test1, test2]
    B: [test3, test4]
    C: [test5, test6]
    D: [test7]
```

Then use it in the selection. For example, if you enter `site=A`

```yaml
  rooms: "{{ sites_dict[site] }}"
```

gives

```yaml
  rooms: [test1, test2]
```

---

Example of a complete playbook for testing

```yaml
- hosts: localhost

  vars:

    sites:
      - rooms: [test1, test2]
        site: A
      - rooms: [test3, test4]
        site: B
      - rooms: [test5, test6]
        site: C
      - rooms: [test7]
        site: D

    sites_dict: "{{ sites|items2dict(key_name='site', value_name='rooms') }}"
    rooms: "{{ sites_dict[site] }}"

  vars_prompt:
    - name: site
      prompt: "What site are we working with [A,B,C,D] ?"
      private: no

  tasks:

    - debug:
        var: sites_dict|to_yaml
    - debug:
        var: rooms|to_yaml
```